# Heroku [RuntimeException]An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"

Tags: php, git, symfony, heroku

Trying to get push master on Heroku

Here's the log :

> -----> PHP app detected
>
> -----> Bootstrapping...
>
> -----> Installing platform packages...
>
> ```
>    - php (7.2.5)
>
>    - nginx (1.8.1)
>
>    - apache (2.4.33)
> ```
>
> -----> Installing dependencies...
>
> ```
>    Composer version 1.6.4 2018-04-13 12:04:24
>
>    Loading composer repositories with package information
>
>    Installing dependencies from lock file
>
>    Package operations: 47 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
>      - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.7): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.3.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.6.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/common (v2.6.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.5.13): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing twig/twig (v1.35.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing paragonie/random_compat (v2.0.11): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-util (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-php56 (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/symfony (v3.4.6): Downloading (100%)         
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-intl-icu (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/polyfill-apcu (v1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing psr/simple-cache (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing psr/log (1.0.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing psr/link (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing psr/container (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing psr/cache (1.0.1): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing fig/link-util (1.0.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle (1.3.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/instantiator (1.0.5): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing twig/extensions (v1.5.1): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing sensio/framework-extra-bundle (v5.1.4): Downloading (100%)         
>
>      - Installing pagerfanta/pagerfanta (v1.0.5): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/orm (v2.5.14): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing jdorn/sql-formatter (v1.2.17): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing doctrine/doctrine-bundle (1.8.1): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing easycorp/easyadmin-bundle (v1.17.12): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing friendsofsymfony/user-bundle (v2.1.1): Downloading (100%)         
>
>      - Installing incenteev/composer-parameter-handler (v2.1.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing knplabs/knp-components (1.3.7): Downloading (100%)         
>
>      - Installing knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle (v2.7.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing mgilet/notification-bundle (2.0.3): Downloading (100%)         
>
>      - Installing composer/ca-bundle (1.1.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing sensiolabs/security-checker (v4.1.7): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v5.0.21): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing kriswallsmith/assetic (v1.4.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/assetic-bundle (v2.8.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing monolog/monolog (1.23.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/monolog-bundle (v3.1.2): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.4.9): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing symfony/swiftmailer-bundle (v2.6.7): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing jms/metadata (1.6.0): Downloading (100%)
>
>      - Installing vich/uploader-bundle (1.4.2): Downloading (100%)         
>
>    Generating optimized autoload files
>
>    > Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters
>
>    Creating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
>
>    > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap
>
>    > Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
>
>    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in
> ```
>
> /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php:41
>
> ```
>    Stack trace:
>
>    #0 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(212):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache->doFetch('DoctrineNamespa...')
>
> ```
>    #1 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(185):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespaceVersion()
>
> ```
>    #2 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(78):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespacedId('AppBundle\Entit...')
>
> ```
>    #3 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(211):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->fetch('AppBundle\Entit...')
>
> ```
>    #4 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/d in /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php
> ```
>
> on line 41
>
> ```
>    Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache
> ```
>
> handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception
>
> ```
>      [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                                                                      
>
>      An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:                                                                                                                                               
>
>
>
>
>
>
>
>      PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Doctrine\Common\Cache\apc_fetch() in
> ```
>
> /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php:41
>
> ```
>      Stack trace:                                                                                                                                                                                                            
>
>      #0 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(212):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache->doFetch('DoctrineNamespa...')
>
> ```
>      #1 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(185):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespaceVersion()
>
> ```
>      #2 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php(78):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->getNamespacedId('AppBundle\Entit...')
>
> ```
>      #3 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php(211):
> ```
>
> Doctrine\Common\Cache\CacheProvider->fetch('AppBundle\Entit...')
>
> ```
>      #4 /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/d in /tmp/build_1dba4daecef38b7f372c2a799dfdbfa5/vendor/doctrine/cache/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/ApcCache.php
> ```
>
> on line 41
>
> ```
>    install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
> ```
>
> [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose]
>   [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative]
>   [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] []...
>
> !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app.
>
> !     Push failed

The cache is already empty in my app

Here's my config_prod.yml :

```
    imports:
    - { resource: config.yml }

#doctrine:
#    orm:
#        metadata_cache_driver: apc
#        result_cache_driver: apc
#        query_cache_driver: apc

monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: nested
        nested:
            type: stream
            path: 'php://stderr'
            level: debug
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver: apc
```

I have also did :

```
heroku config:set SYMFONY_ENV=prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using apc, but it looks like you don't have the extension installed, try adding it in your composer.json

```
"require": {
    "ext-apcu": "*"
}
```